# SearchView not getting focus

Tags: android, searchview

**EDIT** For anyone wondering, my problem was I was using `android.widget.SearchView` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`. I hope this helps anyone else with the same problem!

**Original Post**

I'm trying to implement SearchView in the Android ActionBar as per the official guide: http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

After failing to find the problem, I finally stripped down to the most basic Hello World application and found to my surprise that the bug still persists in a minimal app!

Here's the bug:
The search icon appears in the menu bar, no problem. When I click it, the search bar expands (as expected) but there is no cursor and no soft keyboard appears. (I want to post a picture but my reputation is too low :(

Here is the relevant code, although I literally just created a new Android Application and added the item to menu/menu_main.xml.
MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

menu_main.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@android:string/search_go"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

Comment: You should answer and accept the answer to your own question with the detail you placed in the edit  as it is the correct solution.

Comment: Thank you! You've pointed me in the right direction, it's just that now we should be using androidx: `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this is menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="your activity context here"><item
    android:id="@+id/mi_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:icon="@drawable/searchicon"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

and this code in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.mi_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

in `onOptionsItemSelected()`:

```
case R.id.mi_search:
    onSearchRequested();
    break;
```

Comment: Wow, the only trick was
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
instead of
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
Your answer gave a hint in the right direction, if you can edit it for me I'll mark yours as the correct solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Here in 2022 this question still applies but the answer must be updated if you use androidx (which you should).

The menu item must use `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` instead of either  `android.widget.SearchView` or `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`.

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@android:string/search_go"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />
```

The `onCreateOptionmenu` override must also be updated to use the androidx class. Here is the Kotlin code for that:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean { 
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    val searchManager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        menu.findItem(R.id.search).actionView as androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView).apply {
        setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))
    }
}
```